# Windows phone 7 scrollviewer problem

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I am not able to scroll through the page in wp7 . eventhough i have added scrollview it still doesnt work.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="860"
x:Class="sastadeal.PhonePage1"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Height="1768">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="1768">
    <ScrollViewer>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
<!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="24,8,0,-8" Background="#FF61B1DE" Height="1768" >

        <Image Height="76" Margin="8,8,0,0" Source="logo.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Account Purpose" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb" Height="70" Margin="36,161,185,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Background="#FF00BEEF">
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="lb_vendor" Content="Launch &amp; Grab Deals"/>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="lb_customer" Content="Grab Deals"/>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,252,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter You Vendor Code" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="Vendorcode_tb"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="vendorcode_text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,283,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,363,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="e-Mail ID-" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,390,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,466,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter Password - " Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="pwd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,497,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="pwdr" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,596,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,569,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Re-enter password" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,669,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contact Number -" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Cno_txt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,700,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335" InputScope="Number"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,776,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Mobile Number- " Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="mno_text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,807,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,898,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address 1" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,950,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" x:Name="add1_text" Width="335" InputScope="PostalAddress" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,1026,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address 2" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,1057,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>

    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The Screen automatically goes back to its previous location and the scroll is not complete. It just moves down and than back again like an elastic

Comment: +1 for supplying Xaml as well as problem description.

Comment: Using the Margin property for layout is not very flexible, requires a lot of work to get just right, and makes it really hard to make changes. You should consider the other layout panels such as StackPanel for layout.

Comment: even i am thinking of using stackpanel for next page in app to display tiles like buttons <image converts>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `Grid`, that is the only child of the `ScrollViewer`, has a fixed height of 1768. That determines the maximum area that can be scrolled up/down by the `ScrollViewer`.

Your `ScrollViewer` stretches to fit its parent by default. That parent is another `Grid` that also has a fixed height of 1768.

*Therefore the ScrollViewer has a fixed height of 1768 as well, so there is nothing to scroll.* The amount available to scroll is the difference between the `ScrollViewer` height and the content height. In this case the difference is 0.

**Remove the fixed height of the outer Grid.** I doubt your Windows Phone has a 1768 high screen :)

Comment: Thanks... i m such a fool though :p