# Scrollable when keyboard displayed?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a registration form on my layout grid, made out of a stackPanel. Textboxes are taking most of the screen (800px) along with a button. When user is positioned in one of the text boxes, keyboard covers almost half the screen and in order to access boxes below, they first have to click somewhere blank to remove the keyboard and then click another box. It isn't possible to scroll down.

I want to enable same behaviour like when editing name in contacts, but didn't manage yet. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it into a ListBox or a ScrollViewer (probably easier), like so:

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
  ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Also, check to make sure you don't have the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527744/windows-phone-7-scrollviewer-problem).

Comment: Can't access the msdn link.It give `You are not authorized to perform this action.`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I provided an example

Comment: @Eugine I don't have proper account to access this link :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a WP7 developer but here's what I do in Android and iOS and you may get a hint of what to do.

I wrap my forms in a Scrollable View.  This gives easy scrollable features to users without the need of anything else.